# Como usar a tag Language?

Tags: suporte

Ta ai um recurso muito bom e escondido que não sei como usar corretamente. Como eu defino uma linguagem para um bloco de código? Eu lembro que era algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<!-- language-all: lang.vb -->
```

eu não me lembro muito bem como é, só sei que tem por antes do código, não no código...

Comment: `<!-- language-all: lang-vb -->` vale para todos os códigos da postagem, `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` vale para a que vem a seguir. `<!-- language-all: none -->` desliga a colorização.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado!

Comment: Eu acho que a sua pergunta é semi-duplicata dessa, veja se ajuda: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/podemos-ter-syntax-highlight-nos-c%c3%b3digos-como-no-so - Notar que atualmente a maior parte das vezes você só precisa do html comment se o sistema não detectar por conta própria.

Comment: Lembrando que as tags da pergunta já definem a linguagem padrão de highlight nos códigos postados (na pergunta ou na resposta). Você só precisa forçar outra linguagem em casos excepcionais.